# How to parse values from a JWT token in Spring and assign to variable?

Tags: java, spring, jwt

So I am currently getting my JWT token and console logging it values like so:

```
JwtAuthenticationToken authToken = (JWTAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

if (authToken != null) {
    log.warn("Principal authorities:");
    authToken.getAuthorities().forEach(auth -> log.warn("authorities: [{}]", auth.getAuthority()));

Map<String, Object> attributes = Collections.emptyMap();
attributes = authToken.getTokenAttributes();
log.warn("Token attributes:");
attributes
    .entrySet()
    .forEach(attr -> log.warn("attributes: [{}:{}", attr.getKey(), attr.getValue()));
```

Portion of my JWT is the following:

```
{
 "exp": 17283445,
 "iat": 17283445,
 .....
 "realm_access": {
  "roles": [
   "app-user"
  ]
 }
}
```

If lets say I wanted to extract values in roles "app-user" and assign in to a variables,  how would I extract that?

I have console logged my JWT attributes, but not how how to extract indiviual values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this after adding [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) dependency to your project:

```
private void getUserRoles(String jsonStr) {
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
  JSONArray arrayOfTests = (JSONArray) ((JSONObject) json.get("realm_access")).get("roles");
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfTests.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(arrayOfTests.get(i));
  }
}
```

And in your method:

```
getUserRoles(authToken.getTokenAttributes().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, Maps in Java are saved using KV relationships, or KEY-VALUE. And you can access the maps using `get(key)`.

In your case, you could do like this:

```
Map<String, Object> realm_access = (Map<String, Object>) attributes.get("realm_access");

List<String> roles = (List<String>) realm_access.get("roles");
```

You need the `(Map<String, Object>)` and `(List<String>)` so Java knows you are getting a map from within your map, and List of String from the map, else if would in both cases expect Object.

From here you can get roles any of these ways:

```
// To get first role
log.warn(roles.get(0));

// To get all roles
for (int i = 0; i < roles.size(); i++) {
    log.warn(roles.get(i));
}
```

Comment: what is jsonMap?

Comment: Was experimenting his map 'layout' using my Map from another code, forgot to change name to attributes